# The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:

Tags: java, maven

I am getting the following error while building my application using Maven.

> **The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]**

I have tried including `javax.sql:jdbc-stdext` in pom.xml. But it doesnt work either

`pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dpxpay</groupId>
    <artifactId>uTransfercore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>uTransfercore</name>
    <description>uTransfer_core</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcs/jcs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.35</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

I expect it to run successfully. But shows error.

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong? I am new to Maven. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see jdbc-stdext in your pom file. Can you share how you added it?

Comment: Added the following along with the dependencies


``<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.sql/jdbc-stdext -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>``

Comment: Try to remove local repository by removing the folder `c:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository` and rebuild the solution

Comment: Tried it. Still not working.

Comment: *resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced* Try to use -U option to force the update

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the dependency for mysql-connector:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

This dependency is used as a transitive dependency for `jcs:jcs:1.3`

Comment: Please be aware that you should not explicitly use `jdbc-stdext` library. It is used as a transitive dependency for `jcs:jcs:1.3`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the jcs dependency to the following and it worked.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jcs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also added dependency for `javax.servlet`